# VS2015 and clang compile this code, but g++ rejects it. Which one is correct?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, friend

`VS2015` and `clang` compile this code, but [`g++` rejects it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a59ce39b08701fab).

```
namespace A {
   struct B {
      friend void f();
   };
}
void A::f() {}

int main(){
}
```

I think g++ is right because of this Note in [7.3.1.2/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.memdef#3):

> If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class,
>   function, class template or function template<sup>97</sup> the friend is a member
>   of the innermost enclosing namespace. The friend declaration does not
>   by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup
>   ([basic.lookup.unqual]) or qualified lookup ([basic.lookup.qual]).
>   [ Note: **The name of the friend will be visible in its namespace if a
>   matching declaration is provided at namespace scope (either before or
>   after the class definition granting friendship).**  — end note ] If a
>   friend function or function template is called, its name may be found
>   by the name lookup that considers functions from namespaces and
>   classes associated with the types of the function arguments
>   ([basic.lookup.argdep]). If the name in a friend declaration is
>   neither qualified nor a template-id and the declaration is a function
>   or an elaborated-type-specifier, the lookup to determine whether the
>   entity has been previously declared shall not consider any scopes
>   outside the innermost enclosing namespace. [ Note: The other forms of
>   friend declarations cannot declare a new member of the innermost
>   enclosing namespace and thus follow the usual lookup rules.  — end
>   note ]

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600050/clang-a-friend-function-defined-within-a-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part of your quote is more definitive than the note you emphasized:

> The friend declaration does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup ([basic.lookup.unqual]) or qualified lookup ([basic.lookup.qual]).

Your definition relies on qualified lookup to find a function already declared inside the namespace.  But the name is not visible to qualified lookup.  This code should be rejected.

Here's a related rule, found in secion 8.3 `[dcl.meaning]`:

> When the declarator-id is qualified, the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member of the class or namespace to which the qualiﬁer refers (or, in the case of a namespace, of an element of the inline namespace set of that namespace) or to a specialization thereof; the member shall not merely have been introduced by a using-declaration in the scope of the class or namespace nominated by the nested-name-specifier of the declarator-id .